# gedit plugin development in C

Tags: gnome, programming, gedit

I'm interesting in writing gedit plugins in C. I've checked the [Gedit/NewMDIPluginHowTo](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Attic/NewMDIPluginHowTo) but I find it not good to start.

Where can I get more information about writing gedit plugins in C?

Comment: You may get better answers by asking this on [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or the [ubuntu forums programming talk](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=39). I do however believe this question is within the scope of this site as Gedit is a deault application on Ubuntu.

Comment: in the irc chanel irc.gnome.org there is a gedit chanel you can ask there better

Comment: when i contact the channel it say "connection refused"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can start from the sources of existing plugins that you can find here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit-plugins

Try to compile and hack some existing plugin and you will build more experience to create your own one :)